# Streaming protocol for casting mp4 videos in custom receiver application chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am using custom receiver application for casting playready videos using smooth streaming protocol.
I am able to cast the videos of extension .ism/Manifest.
Using that same receiver application will I be able to cast the mp4 videos??
If yes, then what streaming protocol will I have to use??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it your own custom receiver? If so, it depends on you. If you are using MPL for Smooth Streaming, you wouldn't want to use that for mp4; add logic to your receiver to pass that directly to your MediaElement, for example. If you want to use the Default Receiver or Styled Receiver, then they handle both adaptive and mp4.